# Using same stored procedure across MVC controllers

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, stored-procedures

I am developing a MVC application, please let me know the best way to select a stored procedure.

1. Loading a kendo grid on page load AutoBind(True)
2. Select a record from grid and showing the details in another view
   below the grid.( this is also working fine)
3. Now I am editing the info in the below    view and saving the
       information back to the grid (Am calling a SP    here)
4. Loading the grid with the updated dated details on save.

Now my question is can I share the same stored procedure for save and load the records back to the grid. Am i following the separation of concerns or am missing some thing. Please do suggest the best way to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you should use separate stored procedures to do this.  Stored procedures (in my opinion anyway) should do the minimum necessary to get their job done.  When you talk about a single stored procedure being responsible for both `UPDATE` and `SELECT` operations, you introduce potential for very odd behavior.

You CAN techinically do this however

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.myobject_update_and_retrieve
( @UdpateParam1 varchar(25), @UpdateParam2 int, @UpdatedItemId int )
AS 
BEGIN

UPDATE Items
SET UpdateParam1 = @UpdateParam1,
    UpdateParam2 = @UpdateParam2
WHERE UpdatedItemId = @UpdatedItemId

SELECT UpdateParam1,UpdateParam2
FROM   Items

END
```

This is not desirable because you would need to call `ExecuteReader` instead of the intended `ExecuteNonQuery` here.  You lose some of the things provided for you by calling `ExecuteNonQuery` for running `INSERT,UPDATE,DELETE` based stored procedures.

This also creates easier units to test

I would recommend two separate procedures as shown below

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.myobject_update
( @UdpateParam1 varchar(25), @UpdateParam2 int, @UpdatedItemId int )
AS 
BEGIN

UPDATE myobjects
SET Col1 = @UpdateParam1,
    Col2 = @UpdateParam2
WHERE Id = @UpdatedItemId

END
```

and

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.myobject_retrieve
AS
BEGIN
SELECT Col1,Col2,Id FROM myobjects
END
```

Comment: np hope it was helpful